# Cannot remove Event Listeners from object on Angular

Tags: angular, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have an image with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` attributes. When the cursor first hovers this image, it calls `startCalc(id)` method and in this I am calculating some stats with `addEventListener`. When the cursor leaves this image I call `stopCalc()` and in this method I save my calculations, then remove event listeners. But event listeners are not removing.

Here is my code:

```html
    <img id="img-1" class="img" (mouseenter)="startCalc('img-1')" (mouseleave)="stopCalc()" src="{{url}}" />
```

Backend side:

```js
    startCalc(imgID: string) {
        var img = document.getElementById(imgID);
        img.addEventListener("mousemove", calc);
        
        function calc(e) { 
            // doing some calculations
        }
    }
    
    stopCalc() {
        // saving those calculations

        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("img");
    
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].addEventListener("mousemove", null);
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you need to use the removeEventListener method instead. My guess is just adding another null event listener to doesn’t remove the first one, at least not on the browser your testing in, but I’d have to check to make sure (hence my comment instead of an answer).

Comment: You're never actually [removing](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp) the event listener.

Comment: I don't know how to reach calc function from stopCalc method, because of this I am adding another null event listener to override previous one.

Comment: @YSFKBDY It does not work like that. You can put several event listeners on an element for the same event. You are not replacing the previous listener, you are just adding a new `EventListener` that does nothing. You should call `removeEventListener` instead. Also, I don't get why you don't use `(mousemove)` directly. Can you explain what you want to do ? Maybe we can help to do it in a more Angular friendly way